# Вопрос по синтаксису кода

Tags: java

```
public ActionListener choice (JButton b) {
    ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (b.getBackground().equals(Color.RED)) {
                b.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            } else {
                b.setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
        }
    };  //ПОЧЕМУ СДЕСЬ НУЖНО СТАВИТЬ ";" ?
    return actionListener;
}
```

Не могу понять, почему в указаном в коде месте компилятор требует "точку запятую"

Comment: Потому, что это конец операции присвоения.

Comment: Точно. Спасибо. А я смотрел на операцию как на  метод.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev: Ну, хм, а почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD мне всё время кажется неприемлемым писать столь примитивные вещи в форме ответа.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev: Ну, можно дополнить полезными общими рассуждениями, которые показывают, как правильно думать в таких ситуациях. Объяснить, что определение класса в Java, в отличие от многих других популярных языков, может быть частью _выражения_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Компилятор требует точку с запятой, потому что там заканчивается оператор присвоения. То есть вы создаете анонимный класс и его же сразу присваиваете переменной `actionListener`. Естественно, в таком случае нужна точка с запятой.

Это легко поняв представив, что вы вынесли объявления класса во метод или сам класс, например:

```
public ActionListener choice (JButton b) {
    ActionListener actionListener = getActionListener();  //ПОЧЕМУ СДЕСЬ НУЖНО СТАВИТЬ ";" ?
    return actionListener;
}

private ActionListener getActionListener() {
   return new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (b.getBackground().equals(Color.RED)) {
                b.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            } else {
                b.setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

или так

```
public ActionListener choice (JButton b) {
    ActionListener actionListener = new MyActionListener();  //ПОЧЕМУ СДЕСЬ НУЖНО СТАВИТЬ ";" ?
    return actionListener;
}

private class MyActionListener extends ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (b.getBackground().equals(Color.RED)) {
            b.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        } else {
            b.setBackground(Color.RED);
        }
    }
}
```